# Facebook & Rackspace CDN

Tags: facebook, rackspace

I have been using Rackspace's CDN for a number of months now. All of sudden a number of users are complaining about this error:

> You can't post this because it has a blocked link The content you're
>   trying to share includes a link that our security systems detected to
>   be unsafe:
>
> cf5.rackcdn.com
>
> Please remove this link to continue.
>
> If you think you're seeing this by mistake, please let us know.

I am using the HTTPS link for the content, and have no idea what changed to flag the URL. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: This site is for programming questions. You've provided no code and no operational details, just a symtom. Perhaps you'd be better off with Facebook general tech support.

Comment: I'm well aware of the nature of this forum. I am asking if someone with web experience has experienced this issue and a way getting around it.

Comment: Can you post one of the links?

Comment: https://beahero.raffleready.com/be-a-hero-raffle -- This happens when you click the top-left "F" Facebook link that opens the sharer window. I'm using Bitly for shortening the URL.

Comment: I asume they are smart enough to follow the short URL through to its destination and still block the content?

Answer (score 0):

David,

Easy fix- I ran into this problem. What you need to do is keep your images all on your shared TLD. Setup a CNAME in your DNS settings (eg. cdn1.example.com) and all image links in your open graph tags should be served through this CNAME.

Fixed the problem instantly for me.

-Derek

Comment: Pretty sure this won't work with HTTPS URIs.  See last lines here: https://www.rackspace.com/knowledge_center/article/using-cnames-with-cloud-files-containers